# Same SHA1 hash for several different files - python

Tags: python, hash, hashmap, sha1

I am using a SHA1 hash to identify identical files within directories and then delete the duplicates.  Whenever I run my script, it seems that an appropriate hash is created for most of my files.  However, I have several files that are very different that are coming up with the same hash.  I know it is virtually impossible for collisions like this to occur, so am wondering if there is something wrong in my code below:

```
hashmap = {}
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(maindirectory):
    for filename in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(fullname) as f:
            d = f.read()
            h = hashlib.sha1(d).hexdigest()
            filelist = hashmap.setdefault(h, [])
            filelist.append(fullname)
# delete records in dictionary that have only 1 item (meaning no duplicate)
for k, v in hashmap.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        del hashmap[k]
```

When I return my dictionary, hashmap, there are a few predictable duplicates and then there is one hash with about 40 unique files.  Any suggestions, tips, or explanations would be most appreciated!

Comment: you're probably reading/hashing `.` and `..`?

Comment: I think you should open the files in `b` mode: `open(fullname, 'rb')`

Comment: Could you provide the values for `hashmap` that running this returns?

Comment: Rawing - it appears that this worked on my test directories.  Once I run it on my full directories, I will update.  In the meantime, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept as answer.  Thank you!